# Installing Babel on Ubuntu 16.0.4

Tags: babeljs

I'm trying to install Babel (https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation) on Ubuntu 16.0.4. I can't seem to get it to install though:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-cli
â
â â¢âââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââ
loadDep:for-in            â â¢âââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââ
loadDep:set-immediate-shi â â¢âââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââ
loadDep:util-deprecate â  â â¢âââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââ
loadRequestedDeps         â â¢âââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââ
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
runTopLevelLifecycles     â
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.2.3
npm WARN admin No description
npm WARN admin No repository field.
npm WARN admin No license field.
runTopLevelLifecycles     â
```

**package.json** exists and just has `{}` as the contents. When I check the version number I get:

```
babel --version
6.26.0 (babel-core 6.26.3)
```

I'm then trying to set this plugin up:

https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-template-literals/

I run:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-es2015-template-literals
```

**.babelrc** has the following contents in:

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-es2015-template-literals"]
}
```

Yet when I try and run this plugin it spits out a horrible error:

```
babel --plugins transform-es2015-template-literals /home/chambres/web/xxx.org/public_html/2018/js/lib-non-es6/categories.js
ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "transform-es2015-template-literals" specified in "base" at 0, attempted to resolve relative to "/home/chambres/web/xxx.org/public_html/2018/js/lib-non-es6"
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:180:17
    at Array.map (native)
    at Function.normalisePlugins (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:158:20)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:234:36)
    at OptionManager.init (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:368:12)
    at File.initOptions (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:212:65)
    at new File (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:135:24)
    at Pipeline.transform (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:46:16)
    at transform (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/babel/util.js:50:22)
    at Object.compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/babel/util.js:59:12)
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Given the path you posted: `home/chambres/web/xxx.org/public_html/2018/js/lib-non-es6`, where is your `node_modules` folder where the plugin is installed?

Comment: @loganfsmyth sorry for the late reply. I fell asleep :) I'm still pretty new to all this node stuff. After your comment, I realised that I should be installing the plugin directly in the folder I want to run it in. After doing that, the command runs fine now and does its magic :) Could you put that as an answer so I can accept? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly install it globally by using: `sudo npm install -g babel-cli`